# sql query performance when using functions in where condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query

```
select e_name 
from my_table 
where year_week between yearweek('2021-11-10') and yearweek('2021-11-18');
```

will the `yearweek('2021-11-10')` function be executed only once, before the execution, or will it be calculated for each row?

is it better to calculate it before?

```
select e_name 
from my_table 
where year_week between 202145 and 202146;
```

note: the `yearweek` func gets a static variable - and does not depened on the db rows

Comment: *will the yearweek('2021-11-10') function be executed only once, before the execution, or will it be calculated for each row?* All constant expressions (including ones in interest) are evaluated during execution plan building. Of course, they are calculated once. *is it better to calculate it before?* No difference. But the former query is more clear.

Comment: In general, function calls _with constant arguments_ take an insignificant amount of time.  Fetching the row(s) takes a _lot_ more time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/where-optimization.html says:

> Constant expressions used by indexes are evaluated only once.